# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment or one of its dependencies error in an ASP.NET Webforms site

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application which I have recently upgraded to .NET 4.0 which uses VS2013. It was originally build in VS2010. It also uses DevExpress controls Version 16.2

When I try and build the site I get the following errors: -

```
    Error   1   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment,            Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.       
Error   3   Type 'EventArgs' is not defined.    App_Code\Global.asax.vb 41  62  Optima Online V2
Error   5   Type 'Object' is not defined.   App_Code\Global.asax.vb 52  48  Optima Online V2
Error   6   'DateTime' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. App_Code\Global.asax.vb 59  61  Optima Online V2
Error   7   Type 'EventArgs' is not defined.    App_Code\Global.asax.vb 71  62  Optima Online V2
Error   8   Type 'EventArgs' is not defined.    App_Code\Global.asax.vb 77  73  Optima Online V2
Error   9   Type 'EventArgs' is not defined.    App_Code\Global.asax.vb 83  80  Optima Online V2
Error   10  Type 'EventArgs' is not defined.    App_Code\Global.asax.vb 88  66  Optima Online V2
Error   13  'ServerErrorSection' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   App_Code\Global.asax.vb 98  98  Optima Online V2
Error   14  Type 'EmailException' is not defined.   App_Code\Global.asax.vb 102 25  Optima Online V2
Error   15  Type 'EventArgs' is not defined.    App_Code\Global.asax.vb 108 56  Optima Online V2
Error   16  Type 'EventArgs' is not defined.    App_Code\Global.asax.vb 112 60  Optima Online V2
Error   17  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\OptimaOnlineBLL.vb 345 167 Optima Online V2
Error   18  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\OptimaOnlineBLL.vb 345 205 Optima Online V2
Error   19  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\OptimaOnlineBLL.vb 348 27  Optima Online V2
Error   20  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\OptimaOnlineBLL.vb 351 32  Optima Online V2
Error   21  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\OptimaOnlineBLL.vb 356 37  Optima Online V2
Error   22  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\OptimaOnlineBLL.vb 358 38  Optima Online V2
Error   23  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\OptimaOnlineBLL.vb 362 42  Optima Online V2
Error   24  Type 'Collection' is not defined.   App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    13  33  Optima Online V2
Error   25  'HttpContext' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    31  23  Optima Online V2
Error   26  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    104 38  Optima Online V2
Error   27  Type 'Collection' is not defined.   App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    106 51  Optima Online V2
Error   28  'Convert' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    125 41  Optima Online V2
Error   31  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    132 42  Optima Online V2
Error   33  Type 'Collection' is not defined.   App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    137 54  Optima Online V2
Error   34  Type 'Collection' is not defined.   App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    505 80  Optima Online V2
Error   35  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    505 95  Optima Online V2
Error   36  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    506 26  Optima Online V2
Error   37  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    532 63  Optima Online V2
Error   38  Type 'ArrayList' is not defined.    App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    533 28  Optima Online V2
Error   39  'ConfigurationManager' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    579 57  Optima Online V2
Error   40  'ConfigurationManager' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    648 57  Optima Online V2
Error   41  Type 'Collection' is not defined.   App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    692 32  Optima Online V2
Error   42  'ConfigurationManager' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    775 57  Optima Online V2
Error   43  'IIf' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    787 43  Optima Online V2
Error   44  'IIf' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  App_Code\personalisedItem.vb    801 43  Optima Online V2
```

I have seen fixes for the first error by adding a dependant assembly reference to the Web.config file in ASP.NET MVC but that doesn't seem to work.

I am also at a loss to figure out why things like collections and EventArgs cannot be referenced.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

"The system cannot find the file specified." - your path is wrong. You may check also the specific version setting.
You can see the binding paths if you set the  reg value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to add :-

```
<runtime>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

to the web.config file

**AND**

put the DLL in the bin folder in order to get the application to build correctly.